# How to get missing icons in dark theme mode of Ubuntu 20.04 with Gnome flashback?

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

After installing Ubuntu 20.04 I had switched to dark theme mode; after which I installed Gnome flashback. However, in this case the notification icons also appears dark as shown in the image below. ***How can this be corrected ?*** The time panel seems to work fine.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change icon theme from `ubuntu-mono-light` to `ubuntu-mono-dark`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface icon-theme "ubuntu-mono-dark"
```